# Terraform thinks all resources in RG were deleted and wants to create again

Tags: terraform

All of a sudden today when running my Terraform plan, it suddenly thinks that all the resources previously created by Terraform that currently exist in the resource group have been deleted. And it says it will create those objects. Not sure how it got into that state. How can I fix this? The resources are all there...terraform just thinks they are deleted.

Comment: You need to determine what occurred with the state in between the two times. There are multiple possibilities that could have caused this, and approaching from that direction would be the safest and quickest path forward.

Comment: The issue was related to my own oversight. I had forgotten to set the subscription using the az account set command. So essentially my TF script was running against the wrong subscription. After I set the subscription, the script was able to find all the resources again. Entirely my fault! But appreciate everyone's suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to manually import the resources into tfstate: https://www.terraform.io/cli/import

Each resource should have its own documentation for importing - you'll need to evaluate each resource's docs in the Terraform registry. Import instructions are usually listed at the end of the docs

e.g. for [S3 buckets](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket)

> Import
>
> S3 bucket can be imported using the bucket, e.g.,
>
> $ terraform import aws_s3_bucket.bucket bucket-name

Make sure that your tfstate has a remote backend where the [state is stored](https://www.terraform.io/language/state/remote) after provisioning, and read from before provisioning - if there's no tfstate, Terraform can only infer that there are no resources

Comment: Thanks for the response! I will try it out and report back